# Django Error - ImportError: cannot import name get_cache

Tags: django

I was running my project using Django 1.8 and it was working properly. But then I had to upgrade Django to 1.9 now when I again run my project it gave an error - ImportError: cannot import name get_cache.

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

and I get following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/vermahim17/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350,
  in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
File "/home/vermahim17/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
  line 324, in execute django.setup()
File "/home/vermahim17/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py",
  line 18, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/vermahim17/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
  line 85, in populate app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/vermahim17/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
  line 90, in create module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py",
  line 37, in import_module __import__(name)
File "/home/vermahim17/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keyedcache/__init__.py",
  line 27, in <module>
from django.core.cache import get_cache, InvalidCacheBackendError, DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS ImportError: cannot import name get_cache
```

Comment: From error message it is evident that the keyedcache package version is not compatible with Django 1.9

Comment: P.S `syncdb` has been deprecated. You should be using `migrate`

Answer (score 1):

I think , Django 1.9 doesn't have the provision to import get_cache method. Please look into this to fix

https://github.com/vstoykov/django-imagekit/commit/c26f8a0